# Removing meta and title when sharing on facebook from a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, facebook, wordpress-theming

[image]

Hello guys, is there any way to remove the highlighted (meta, date, author and title) when being shared on Facebook? It looks awful and redundant. I tried several plugins, but it also removes the meta on the page which looks really weird and unnecessary.

I just wanted to remove this when I'm sharing it on facebook/social media.

I'm using the Twenty Seventeen Theme by the way. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses something called the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me) to determine what to display when a website is shared. Basically what it is is a set of meta tags you can add to your HTML head to tell Facebook what to show. If you don't have those meta tags in place, it will try to guess, and sometimes it does a bad job, as you are seeing here.

There are a number of plugins out there that can help give you better control over what Facebook shows by setting up the right meta tags for you. Twitter has it's own set of meta tags it uses so I'd try a plugin that handles multiple services. I'd recommend trying out [Yoast](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/). It does much more than social media meta tags, but the SEO tools it gives you are pretty great too.